# How to convert this relative path to an absolute path?

Tags: python, tkinter, path, filepath, absolute

So, this is a Tkinter - Python software which gets an image from my system's path that I provided but how to change it such that when some one else downloads it and uses their  path to the file is use  I think some abspath can be use .

```
img= PhotoImage(file="D:/Coding GCB/Python (Building)/ProductiveSearch/res/do1.png")
```

Comment: [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

os.path.abspath('<relative to script>/do1.png̈́')
```

[abspath doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=abspath#os.path.abspath)

Answer (score 0):

import os

os.path.abspath("mydir/myfile.txt")

you can also read more on the path module to do this

from pathlib import Path